# What does "shrink the whole nine yards" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In movie **The Departed**, there's a line: "You will be on probation, see a court-ordered shrink......the whole nine yards."

What is shrinking by court order here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In "a court ordered shrink", **a** indicates that what follows is a noun. If you look up [**shrink**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shrink) in a good dictionary, you will find that, as a noun, it means a  psychiatrist. **court-ordered** explains that the court will order you to see a psychiatrist.

[**the whole nine yards**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/whole-bit?q=the%20whole%20nine%20yards) is an idiom meaning the whole of something, including everything related to it.